# Jquery Finding the closest link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I want to be able to get the href from this type of code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class=" sorting_1">
      <a href="aURL">The Link Text</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

but I want to be able to click on the link itself, or the td.

Here is my CoffeeScript:

```
$("#myID tr td").click (event)->
    event.preventDefault()
    link = $(event.target).find("a").attr("href")
    $("#anAjaxPod").load(link)
```

This works if one clicks on the td, but not if if one clicks on the link.

Edit: Updated question, I used find at first. This is just the last code I played with

Comment: From jquery doc :  the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method searches through these elements and their **ancestors** in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Answer (score 4):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) ; [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is to climb up the DOM tree testing self and ancestors. Here anchor tag is the child of td so you need to descend down. So find or a children selector is what you need.

```
$(this).find("a").attr("href")
```

> Closest get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$("#myID tr td").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    link = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $("#anAjaxPod").load(link);
 });
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zesu/)

Answer (score 3):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks and self or ancestors where as you want to descendent, to find the descendent use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
link = $(event.target).find("a").attr("href")
```

Comment: $(event.target).find("a").attr("href") is what I tried at first, but it returns undefined when I click directly on the link.

Comment: addBack makes clicking on the link work, but now clicking on the td doesn't work x_x

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myID tr td").click(function(){
         Link = $(this).find("a").eq(0).attr("href");
         $("#anAjaxPod").load(Link);
         return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Excellent. This solutions works for both cases. Thank you very much!

Comment: The `.eq(0)` part is unnecessary. When using `.attr("href")`, it implicitly gets the `href` property of the **first** matched element...which is what `.eq(0)` is doing. It's just redundant/unnecessary

Comment: And you probably don't want to return false - you should only prevent the default behavior of the event